# Can I make Visual Studio Code highlight staged changes?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code displays a gutter line to indicate some files have changed. When you stage the changes, the line disappears.

This is what unstaged changes looks like:
[image: Unstaged changes in VS Code]

This is what it looks like after running `git add .`:
[image: Staged changes in VS Code]

Is there someway to make VS Code highlight staged changes in the gutter?

Answer (score 19):

Not natively (VS Code) or with [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens))

As you probably know (or written), there is a [feature request](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/396)

> Right now, I know which lines are not staged (green for new, blue for edited) and maybe when I commit locally, highlight those lines in a different color (purple?) to represent "committed but unpublished."

But for now, you need to switch to the version control part of VSCode to see what is about to be committed:

[image: uncommitted but staged]

There you can inspect staged changes to be committed.

Note: there is an [`uncommittedColor`](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blame/414f9c942bf04771498041d77fd2412c9ce6c6fc/src/annotations/annotations.ts#L14-L17), but I don't know if it references staged or unstaged changes, or how it is used.
[GitLens 6.2](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#620---2017-11-27) does mention `gitlens.gutterUncommittedForegroundColor` themable color, but I don't see it anymore in my current 8.3 GitLens version.

---

The [`Microsoft/vscode` 60389](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60389#issuecomment-428463408) opened by the OP includes for now:

> When you're editing a file in Git, there are three versions of it:
>
> - HEAD
> - Index
> - Working tree
>
> So, there are two possible diffs to show:
>
> - `HEAD <> Index`
> - `Index <> Working Tree`
>
> **We currently show gutter decorations for `Index <> Working Tree`**.
> Since the file which is open in the editor is always Working Tree, it doesn't make any sense to show `HEAD <> Index` changes in the gutter, since none of those two files is Working Tree.

---

Aug. 202&: [Lefty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4547852/lefty) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881124/can-i-make-visual-studio-code-highlight-staged-changes#comment121684457_50746390):

> In recent GitLens version its possible to temporarily enable this highlighting by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and entering `gitlens.toggleFileChanges`.
>
> It disappears on first edit though :(.

Comment: I made a feature request against VS Code proper: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60389

Comment: @VanessaPhipps Well done. I will follow this case on GitHub.

Comment: Looks like they didn't take it :( I have a hard time making a counterargument, not that they'd pay attention to one on a closed issue, but somehow IntelliJ manages to make that work...

Comment: In recent GitLens version its possible to temporarily enable this highlighting by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P and entering `gitlens.toggleFileChanges`. It disappears on first edit though :(.

Comment: @Lefty Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.