# Have the git gutter show the diff between the current HEAD and a selected commit/branch in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff, git-diff, git-gutter

I'm referring to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30PtC.png) gutter that shows the diff between the working directory and HEAD. How do I make it show the diff between the working directory (or the HEAD) and a branch of my choosing (say, the master/main)?

Essentially, I want something like the [Git Scope plugin in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope).

Comment: related, but not quite a duplicate of [Can I make Visual Studio Code highlight staged changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48881124/11107541)